# Using functors/lambdas with C callbacks

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback, wrapper

I'm in the process of writing a C++11 wrapper for a popular open-source C library, providing RAII and all the other niceties you'd expect. The wrapper will be header-only (so one only needs to link to the original C lib), and in addition one of the principles I would like to stick to is that the wrapper should be "zero overhead" as far as possible, that is, when optimisation is enabled everything should be inlined so that only the C function calls remain.

For the most part, this isn't all that difficult: I have classes which hold pointers to the (opaque) C types, with constructors which call "create" functions, destructors which call "destroy" functions, methods which call C functions etc etc, just as you'd expect. So far, so easy.

However, one of the problems I'm having is how to deal with callbacks. The library has several entry points of the form

```
typedef <function signature> CallbackType;
void set_callback(CallbackType cb, void* data);
```

such that the underlying C library stores `cb` and `data` in static variables, and when particular events occur, the callback is fired and `data` is passed back to it along with other arguments.

I'd like to provide wrappers so that any C++ callable (i.e. functions, functors, lambdas, method calls using `std::bind` etc) can be used in a callback. However, functors and (capturing) lambdas are objects which need to be stored somewhere in order to ensure that they're still valid when the callback is fired. And exactly where to store them seems problematic... I can't put them on the heap as they then can't be deleted, and I can't (easily) use static variables because of the header-only nature of my library.

Does anyone have any advice/ingenious ideas/hacks that can be used in a situation like this?

Thanks in advance.

<sup>To n.m., if you see this: apologies for the mix-up the other day, I got busted posting this question about a personal project on work time so thought it best to delete it, it only had 5 views at the time so I thought I got away with it but obviously not. I'd be interested in your answer if you don't mind typing it again?</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Place subscription handle and callback object in the single subscription wrapper. Then it's users responsibility to retain this wrapper as long as he wants to get callbacks from your c-library.

```
class subscription
{
    std::function<void(int)> m_f;
    static void callback(int param, void* data)
    {
        static_cast<subscription*>(data)->m_f( param );
    }

    subscription( const subscription& other ) = delete;
    subscription& operator=( const subscription& ) = delete;

public:
    subscription( const std::function<void(int)>& f ) : m_f(f)
    {
        set_callback( &callback, this);
    }
    ~subscription()
    {
        clear_callback(&callback, this);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
subscription s( [](int param){ std::cout<<param*2<<std::endl; } );
```

Comment: That's actually really nice, I hadn't really thought of pushing responsibility onto the user but it does make sense. Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow!